# Noise/Echo during video chat

Tags: webrtc, video-conferencing, opentok, tokbox

I've been using OpenTok in one of my apps and it's working out well. However, I'm having an issue with the sound. I'm getting echo and noise issues during sessions. I've tested it on many different platforms, systems, etc. but the audio is still faulty. Any ideas on what might be causing this and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Echoing can be solved by wearing headphones. Echos usually happen when the computer microphone driver doesn't support echo cancellation, when the microphone is too sensitive, the speakers are turned on too loud, or interference from other electronic devices nearby.